# Is a scheme $X$ projective iff every component of $X$ is projective?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-schemes

Today in a lecture it was claimed

**Proposition** Let $X$ be a proper scheme of finite type and dimension $1$ over a field $k$. Then $X$ is projective.

So, I already knew the above statement for integral curves - and I can see how to drop the condition of being reduced. However, I don't see how to reduce to the case where $X$ is irreducible. The proof of the Proposition was only sketched and this step was actually missing, so I wonder, how one might fix that (and, in particular, if the statement as given holds true).

On further note, what can one say in higher dimensions - is it true that (for finite type $k$-schemes), projectivity can be checked on irreducible components? If not, is there a handy counterexample?

My first attempt in proving such a statement would be looking at the Picard groups of $X$ and its normalization, and then try to argue using ample line bundles. Looking for counterexamples, I am at first sight rather hopeless (because if I recall correctly, counterexamples for proper varieties that are not projective are rather complicated in any case).

Comment: Have you had a look at problem 8 in chapter 3, section 5 of Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry? Maybe it could prove to be of some help.

Comment: Thank you! This should solve the dimension=1 case. How about the arbitrary case though?

Comment: If the irreducible components "intersect" in points then the same method as in the case of curves should given that the map $Pic(X) \rightarrow \oplus_i Pic(X_i)$ is surjective. If not then this method definitely doesnot work. Here is an answer: https://mathoverflow.net/a/57153/58056 (the latter part) which essentially explains what goes into analyzing such things. This is definitely nowhere close to an answer but maybe it shows that there is something non-trivial to do here.

Comment: Cox Little Schenk Toric Varieties book Chapter 6, example 6.1.17 provides an example of a 3 dimensional toric variety that is proper but not projective